# How to know if GetResponseForExceptionEvent happened during or after kernel.terminate?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

If `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` happens before `kernel.response`, then we can set `Response` object and it will be sent to the user. But it if happens after or during `kernel.terminate` (after the actual response has been sent), there is no official way/API to check if a response has already been sent.

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    // how to know if $event this happened after/during kernel.terminate?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ExceptionListener` you can inject `RequestStack` . [RequestStack](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack) documentation say that

> Outside the handling of a request, `$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()`
>   returns null.

So in your listener you can check for `$currentRequest`

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class ExceptionListener
{
    protected $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if (null === $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()) {
             // exception is happen outside the handling of a request
             // so before request is handled and after response has been sent
        }
    }
}
```